# Brownian motion level reaching probability

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

What is the probability that a $B$ Brownian motion reaches the $y=10$ level on time interval $\left[0,100\right]$ and $B_{100}<0$?

My idea is the following...

If we denote the time of reaching the given level as $\tau$, then it is known that $\mathbf{P}\left(\tau\leq t\right)=\mathbf{P}\left(\frac{y^{2}}{Z^{2}}\leq t\right)$, where $Z$ is a standard normal distributed random variable. Because the definition of $\tau$, $B_{\tau}=10$ and $$\left\{ \tau\leq 100\right\} \cap\left\{ B_{\tau}-B_{100}>10\right\} \Longleftrightarrow\left\{ \tau\leq 100\right\} \cap\left\{ 10-B_{100}>10\right\}$$

So in this case, the question is $$\mathbf{P}\left(\left\{ \tau\leq 100\right\} \cap\left\{ B_{\tau}-B_{100}>10\right\} \right) =\mathbf{P}\left(\left\{ \tau\leq 100\right\} \cap\left\{ 10-B_{100}>10\right\} \right)=...$$

Because $B_{\tau}-B_{100}$ is independent from $B_{\tau}$, I think we can continue as
$$\ldots\mathbf{P}\left(\tau\leq 100\right)\cdot\mathbf{P}\left(10-B_{100}>10\right)={\mathbf{P}\left(\frac{10^{2}}{Z^{2}}<100\right)\cdot\mathbf{P}\left(B_{100}<0\right)=\mathbf{P}\left(1<Z^{2}\right)\cdot\frac{1}{2}=}$$

$${\mathbf{P}\left(\left\{ Z<-1\right\} \cup\left\{ Z>1\right\} \right)}\cdot\frac{1}{2}=2\left(1-\varPhi\left(1\right)\right)\cdot\frac{1}{2}=1-\varPhi\left(1\right).$$

Here $\varPhi$ denotes the cumulative distribution function of the standard normal distribution. Is it a good reasoning? Do I miss something? I'm not sure that we can factor the probability into product in the middle, because I'm not sure if $\left\{ \tau\leq t\right\}$  and $\left\{ B_{\tau}-B_{100}>10\right\}$  are independent.

Comment: Tl;dr .Please compare your results with the section Brownian motion and its runing maximum in Karatzas Shreve *Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus.*

Comment: I will check, but it is a wrong result. I wanted to solve it again, but I don't think $\left\{ \tau<100\right\}$ and $\left\{ B_{\tau}-B_{100}>10\right\}$ are independent. But I think the probability that  $\left\{ B_{100}>20\right\}$ is equal the probability I'm looking for. So it should solve the problem.